# SSRS multiple values optional

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

I'm having some issues with SSRS and multi select values. Basically, apart from the Date parameters (@From) and (@To), all other parameters, I want to be optional. Multiple values are allowed and pulled from a query but if the user doesn't want to specify a value I want it to pull all items.

So for example if the Ward parameter hasn't specified a value it includes all values.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT
 rTranslog.[Month]
 ,CONVERT(datetime,rTranslog.LogDateTime, 103) AS [Date]
 ,rTranslog.IssueDate
 ,rTranslog.Site
 ,rTranslog.CaseNo
 ,rTranslog.NSVCode
 ,REPLACE(rProduct.LabelDescription, '!', ' ') AS [Drug] 
 rProduct.ReportGroup
,rTranslog.BNFCode
,rTranslog.Ward
,rConsultant.ConsultantName
,rSpecialty.Description AS [SpecialtyName]
,rTranslog.Kind
,rTranslog.LabelType
,rTranslog.Qty AS [Quantity]
,rTranslog.CostExTax/100 AS [CostGBPExVat]
,rTranslog.Cost/100 AS [CostGBPIncVAT]
,rTranslog.DispId

FROM
 rTranslog
  INNER JOIN rProduct
   ON rTranslog.NSVCode = rProduct.NSVCode
  LEFT JOIN rConsultant
   ON rConsultant.Consultant = rTranslog.Consultant
  LEFT JOIN rSpecialty
   ON rTranslog.Specialty = rSpecialty.SpecialtyCode

WHERE rTranslog.IssueDate BETWEEN (@To) AND (@From) 
  AND rTranslog.Ward IN (@Ward) OR (@Ward) Is Null  
  AND rProduct.LabelDescription IN (@Drug) OR (@Drug) Is Null
  AND rTranslog.CaseNo IN(@CaseNo) OR (@CaseNo) Is Null
  AND rSpecialty.Description IN(@Specialty) OR (@Specialty) Is Null
  AND rTranslog.Site IN (@Site)

ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just a slight change should give you what you want.

```
WHERE rTranslog.IssueDate BETWEEN (@To) AND (@From) 
  AND (rTranslog.Ward IN (@Ward) OR @Ward Is Null)
  AND (rProduct.LabelDescription IN (@Drug) OR @Drug Is Null)
  AND (rTranslog.CaseNo IN(@CaseNo) OR @CaseNo Is Null)
  AND (rSpecialty.Description IN(@Specialty) OR @Specialty Is Null)
  AND rTranslog.Site IN (@Site)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just left work and back in on Thursday. Will give it a try then. Will let you know how I get on ... finger crossed

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't solved it. It's still forcing me to input a value. 'Please select a value for the parameter 'Case No'. It's like that for all of the multi select filters

Comment: That should work. can you post a sample of the data or better still a SQL fiddle with some sample data in that replicates the issue. I do lots of these kinds of queries and never really had any issues.

Comment: I can't send a sample of the data sadly ... Data confidentiality. Will try fiddling with the SQL in design view

Comment: It works in the "Define Query Parameters" when building the report. But doesn't when actually accessing the report

Comment: Do you mean if you run the query in the dataset query designer and pass the parameters in it works ok, but fails if you pass in those same parameters when executing the report?